# MPI Inconsistent Receiver

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Could anyone explain what is going on with this point-to-point communication?

I expected that process #1 will always receives from #0, but most of the time the following happened.

```
Rank[0] Sent
Rank[132802] Got 0.456700
[132802]Source:0    Tag:999999  Error:0
```

Note: sometimes it works properly though. See below.

```
Rank[0] Sent
Rank[1] Got 0.456700
[1]Source:0 Tag:999999  Error:0
```

Compile with `mpicc MPITu.c -o out -Wall`

Execute with `mpiexec -n 5 out 0 1` // I assigned sender and receiver ranks here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int rank, nprocs;
  double data, bag;
  int sender = atoi( argv[1]);
  int target = atoi(argv[2]);
  int Max_Count = 100;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Status status;
  data = .4567;
  int count =10;
  if(rank==sender){
    MPI_Send(&data,count,MPI_DOUBLE,target,999999,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Rank[%d] Sent\n",rank );}
  else if(rank==target) { MPI_Recv(&bag,Max_Count,MPI_DOUBLE,sender,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("Rank[%d] Got %f\n",rank,bag );
    printf("[%d]Source:%d\tTag:%d\tError:%d\n",rank, status.MPI_SOURCE,status.MPI_TAG,status.MP\
I_ERROR);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a programming bug: your 'data' is just a scalar value. In your MPI_send, you are sending count=10 numbers from that address.

Comment: @macelee It fixed! Thank you. Could you also explain the relation between a count number and a rank number? Since it did work sometimes.

Comment: Ranks are addresses, i.e. they designate the sender or the receiver of a message. Counts are counts, i.e. how many elements are there in the message. Both are completely orthogonal.

Comment: In your example, you are sending 'count' number of double precision data located at memory address 'data' to the 'target' rank, giving the message a tag '999999'.